# File parsing with Bash

Tags: bash

For instance, i have this sample.txt with the following line:

> **EX1**~00~00~00~00~00~Hello~122113~00~EX2~This~Is~A~Sample~Data~**EX1**~00~00~00~00~00~Hi~123456~00

I want to get "Hello" and "Hi", both are after **EX1~00~00~00~00~00~**
I already have this line in my bash script, yet I found it too long:

```
grep -oP 'EX1.[\w\s\d]*.[\w\s\d]*.[\w\s\d]*.[\w\s\d]*.[\w\s\d]*.\K[\w\s\d]*' < sample.txt
```

Do you have any suggestions for the betterment of my script? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method you are writing same thing `[\w\s\d]*` five times instead you set a quantifier that matches if it is exactly five times. Also using `\w\d` is same as `\w` since matches any word character`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` writing `\d` or `[0-9]` is not required again.

Try changing your regex to:

```
EX1(?:.[\w\s]*){5}.(\K[\w\s]*)
```

Working: https://regex101.com/r/rF3zN0/1